# Get byte array from MS SQL varbinary

Tags: php, sql-server, varbinary

In my database I use the data type varbinary to store id numbers from my php webpage.

After that when I want to read the ids I get a hexadecimal value like '0x010A'. I have found the php function hexdec for converting hexadecimal values to decimal ones.

But now I don`t know how to split the hex string to get each id separate.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express

Comment: Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/10/31/sql-server-2008-new-binary-hex-string-conversion-functionality-can-dramatically-improve-related-query-performance-by-orders-of-magnitude.aspx

Comment: Thanks ron for your help. I have read the article. A few minutes before I have found a C# method which do what I need. I have rewritten it to PHP and will test it tomorrow at work.

Comment: If you wrote something that works in PHP, I could use it. Can you please post it?

Comment: Sorry, carlo.borreo. I have test the php code an unfortunately it dont worked.